# Why I get p value = NA in Shapiro Wilk test after a BoxCox transformation?

Tags: r, statistics, normalization

this is my first question in this forum which I find very helpful! I have got a problem that I don't know how to interpret or solve it:

I've got measurements of a biochemical parameter (named 'droms') which doesn't reach normality. So, I did a BoxCox transformation following this code:

```
sum(is.na(dataframe$droms))
[1] 0
boxcoxnc(dataframe$droms, method='sw', lambda =seq(-5,5,0.01),plot=TRUE, alpha=0.05, verbose=TRUE)

Error in boxcoxnc(data_turbidez$droms, method = "sw", lambda = seq(-5,  : 
Data must include positive values. Specify shifting parameter, lambda2
```

So, I changed the code to this new one:

```
 boxcoxnc(dataframe$droms, method='sw', lambda2=2, lambda =seq(-5,5,0.01),plot=TRUE, alpha=0.05, verbose=TRUE)

lambda.hat : -0.53 
statistic  : 0.9895904 
p.value    : 0.1819954 

Result     : Transformed data are normal.
```

And I proceeded to apply the transformation:

```
dataframe$droms_normalized <- (dataframe$droms^-0.53-1)/-0.53
```

But when I try to check again the normality looking at the histogram, I don't get the same histogram given by the boxcox transformation and I get this output from the Shapiro Wilk Test:

```
W = NaN, p-value = NA
```

Could you help me to identify what I am doing wrong in the transformation?

Thank you so much!

Comment: It's a pity that you don't provide reproducible sample data. Provided I understood correctly, you're estimating the parameter `lambda` of a *two parameter* Box-Cox transformation (with a non-zero shift parameter `lambda2`). So you need to account for the shift parameter when calculating `dataframe$droms_normalized`. Try `((dataframe$droms + 2)^-0.53-1)/-0.53`.

Comment: Thank you so much!